# How can I remove the URL in the tooltip?

Tags: css, mootools

When using tooltips for links in my admin component, the URL is for some reason visible in the tooltip. Is there a way to turn it off, so that only the title attribute is visible? I'm using the `hasTip` CSS class.

Comment: Shouldn't the class be `hasTooltip`?

Comment: @Lodder Yes, funnily enough, using `hasTooltip` shows a tooltip without the URL, but using `hasTip` produces the error I described. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using CSS class `hasTooltip` instead of `hasTip`.

The manual should be updated to reflect this... https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website